# Cannot run SpringBoot app from IntelliJ run configuration

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, grails, grails-orm

I have a Spring Boot (2.2.5) application that depends on a Grails plugin (4.0.1) that contains domain object models shared across multiple projects.

It all starts up and works well (I can query the database from SB using dynamic finders) when I start using `bootRun` from Gradle, but when I try and start from IntelliJ (2019.1.3) using the Spring Boot run configuration, it throws the exception below.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore' defined in class path resource [org/grails/datastore/gorm/boot/autoconfigure/HibernateGormAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Factory method 'hibernateDatastore' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:135)
    at com.mypackage.MyspringbootApplication.main(MyspringbootApplication.groovy:20)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Factory method 'hibernateDatastore' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.bindSubClass(GrailsDomainBinder.java:1508)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.bindSubClasses(GrailsDomainBinder.java:1467)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.bindRoot(GrailsDomainBinder.java:1410)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.contribute(GrailsDomainBinder.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:283)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.java:287)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:86)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:39)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:23)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:64)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:52)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.ConnectionSourcesInitializer.create(ConnectionSourcesInitializer.groovy:24)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore.<init>(HibernateDatastore.java:200)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore.<init>(HibernateDatastore.java:232)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore.<init>(HibernateDatastore.java:254)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.boot.autoconfigure.HibernateGormAutoConfiguration.hibernateDatastore(HibernateGormAutoConfiguration.groovy:101)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.boot.autoconfigure.HibernateGormAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8266627.CGLIB$hibernateDatastore$13(<generated>)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.boot.autoconfigure.HibernateGormAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8266627$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e1bd1783.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.boot.autoconfigure.HibernateGormAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8266627.hibernateDatastore(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
```

Not the end of the world but IntelliJ exposes some nice features when starting a Spring Boot app using it's built in tool.

Comment: What IDE version is used?

Comment: Good point.. it's 2019.1.3. Will also add to the question

Comment: Have you defined a datasource in the application.properties? I'm pretty sure a missing datasource leads to the hibernate bean not being created

Comment: I have it defined in an application.yml, which of course works fine when I use gradle to start the application.

Comment: "I have a Spring Boot (2.2.5) application that depends on a Grails plugin (4.0.1)" - Is it a Grails application or just a Boot app and you are trying to use a Grails plugin in that Boot app?

Comment: It is a vanilla Spring Boot app for which I am using my own Grails plugin (GORM modelling) as a dependency. Similar to what is done [here] (https://guides.grails.org/gorm-without-grails/guide/index.html) but I did not have to move my domain classes out to `src/main/groovy`.